# Ending Series points don't show up on highchart area type chart for large series data

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts, area-chart

Here is the [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-stock-a1hvg5) of the issue

Preview link (for better visibility): https://highcharts-angular-stock-a1hvg5.stackblitz.io/

Issue is : The last plot that is visible on the right most edge of the chart is of 12/27/2021
[image]

This is wrong as the the series data is available till 12/30/2021 and that should be visible on the right most edge instead of 12/27/2021. It however works when we zoom in slider to 1 year period[image]

How can I make the original chart also display data till 12/30/2021 (series maximum)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by the data-gropuing feature. You can disable the feature:

```
"plotOptions": {
    "area": {
        ...,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

or control anchor behaviour:

```
"plotOptions": {
    "area": {
        ...,
        dataGrouping: {
            anchor: 'end',
            lastAnchor: 'end'
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-stock-mpcl1d

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.dataGrouping

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping